# Two UIPickerViews with Large Data Set

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uipickerview

I would like to create a simple app in Xcode with two UIPickerViews that reference a data set where the second UIPickerView is dependent on the first one. I want to create an app where the user can select the manufacturer of a vehicle; Chevrolet, Dodge, Ford, etc. Then, the user can select the vehicle based on the first choice. For example if "Ford" was selected in the first UIPickerView, then only Ford vehicles show up in the second - F150, Focus, Mustang etc. After selecting both values, the user can search for the average price where the prices are kept in a data set. I found many examples with one UIPickerView referencing arrays, but I want to reference a much larger data set. How would I go about doing this? I am fairly new to Xcode, but I write SAS and SQL code daily.

Comment: Hi - what's the meaning of "How" in your next to last sentence? What's the part you don't understand? Is it that the second wheel content must change dependent on the user choice in the first wheel?

Comment: Use the UIPickerview, it will easy handle many array data. First only enable first pickerview and after selecting first you can enable second one. If user change first pickerview then just reset the second picker view.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have all of records saved in the database. I did something similar with `250k+` records.

1. Do not fetch all of your models' full representation into memory, fetch only one property (string column needed for current picker) with a `DISTINCT` on it - both `SQLite` & `CoreData` allow this.
2. Your subsequent pickers (2nd, 3rd & so on) will automatically see less data becuase of the previous filter applied (only `Ford` vehicles possible options).
3. Rule #1 applies to all of your pickers, only the relevant field as `String` pulled into memory with right filters.

I had no issues at all with above approach with my dataset. Not sure how big your dataset is.